# Sails.js data missing on sails lift with waterline

Tags: node.js, orm, sails.js, waterline

I am using waterline orm which comes by default with sails.js. I recently recognized that my data just goes missing in my MySQL database when I do a sails lift. My model config is alter. Did anyone face similar issues? This is scary.

Comment: If you want to ensure that you don't lose any data you should use 'safe'.

alter doesn't typically delete your data, but if you change the model significantly it can (has happened to me more than once :)).

Answer (score 2):

change your model config to 'safe' so it wont erase your data after you resetart your server..